# Create column with "end date" out of panel data in SAS

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql

I have a dataset that is a panel data, that is many ID's for many moments in time.
It looks like this:

```
ID | Date       | Start date
1  | 01/01/2021 | 01/01/2021
1  | 02/01/2021 | 01/01/2021
1  | 03/01/2021 | 01/01/2021
1  | 20/01/2021 | 20/01/2021
1  | 21/01/2021 | 20/01/2021
2  | 05/01/2021 | 05/01/2021
2  | 06/01/2021 | 05/01/2021
2  | 07/01/2021 | 05/01/2021
3  | 10/01/2021 | 10/01/2021
3  | 11/01/2021 | 10/01/2021
3  | 25/01/2021 | 25/01/2021
```

Where basically, `Date` denotes which days the ID appeared on the table, and `Start date` the start date of some thing happening (doesn't really matter what in this case).

I want to obtain a table like this:

```
ID | Start date | End date 
1  | 01/01/2021 | 03/01/2021
1  | 20/01/2021 | 21/01/2021
2  | 05/01/2021 | 07/01/2021
3  | 10/01/2021 | 11/01/2021
3  | 25/01/2021 | 25/01/2021
```

Where there is one line per "start date" per ID, and the "end date" is added according to the last date in which the person had that "start date".

This is my proposed code but it's clearly missing something, I think mainly how to specify that the "if" should be done for each Start_date. Also, if there's a smarter way to do it with `proc sql` amazing.

```
DATA ArrearsPeriods;
    SET data;
    BY ID Start_date Date;
    RETAIN ID Start_date END_DATE;
    IF last.DateTHEN END_DATE = Date;
RUN;
```

I'm grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer (in proc sql, if anyone has the SAS equivalent, cool!)

```
proc SQL;
create table want as
SELECT a.ID
,      a.Start_date
,      a.Date
FROM Data a
WHERE Start_date IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY ID, Start_date
HAVING Date = max(Date);
QUIT;
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it.

```
DATA ArrearsPeriods;
    SET data;
    BY ID Start_date Date;
    RETAIN end_date;
    IF last.Start_date THEN END_DATE = Date;
RUN;
```

Basically you want the last row for that START_DATE grouping, and then save the DATE value for that.  So you want `if last.start_date`.

Then you need to control the output, of course, and fix up the formatting.  Full code below:

```
data have;
infile datalines dlmstr=' | ';
input ID  Date :ddmmyy10. Start_date :ddmmyy10.;
format date start_date date9.;
datalines;
1  | 01/01/2021 | 01/01/2021
1  | 02/01/2021 | 01/01/2021
1  | 03/01/2021 | 01/01/2021
1  | 20/01/2021 | 20/01/2021
1  | 21/01/2021 | 20/01/2021
2  | 05/01/2021 | 05/01/2021
2  | 06/01/2021 | 05/01/2021
2  | 07/01/2021 | 05/01/2021
3  | 10/01/2021 | 10/01/2021
3  | 11/01/2021 | 10/01/2021
3  | 25/01/2021 | 25/01/2021
;;;;
run;


DATA ArrearsPeriods;
    SET have;
    BY ID Start_date Date;
    RETAIN end_date;
    format end_date date9.;
    IF last.Start_date THEN END_DATE = Date;
    if last.start_date then output;
    drop date;
RUN;
```